# How do I get the user's input from a .html file to a .c file?

Tags: html, c, user-input

I'm trying to get the input from my html webpage, which has a text box and submit button. How can I get the user's input in a separate .c file, so that I can change what happens in my html file depending on the input?

Here is the problem for my assignment: 
If the player input the word NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, or WEST, the program will programmatically generate a webpage that hyperlinks to another room. Do printf() to the browser.

You will need to do something like this:

printf(“< a href=\”http://URL\”>Press HERE to go North< /a>”);

The above printf() will display on the browser a hyperlink. The player will simply click on the word Press HERE to go North with their mouse to cause the browser to change to another webpage. The HTML tag to link to another webpage is:

< a href=”URL”>TEXT TO CLICK< /a>.

You will need to do this for each direction: NORTH, SOUTH, EAST and WEST. If the player input the word GOLD, the program will programmatically generate a webpage that displays the amount of gold pieces the player currently owns and a hyperlink to return the player back to the current room.

Answer (score 0):

Might need a little bit more clarification on what exactly it is you're trying to achieve, but if you do actually want the HTML file to change based on the user's input, depending on whether you want that change to be permanent or based on the individual user, you have a couple of options:

1) If you want the user's input to permanently change the HTML file, have it posted to another server-side page on your website (PHP for example) -- then take the user's input and you can use PHP to write actual changes to the HTML file stored on the server which is delivered to your end users. I would advise being **very** careful with this and make sure you sanitise the input properly to avoid security issues.

2) Alternatively if you want the user's input to change the page they're viewing in some way in real-time and only for that user, you probably want to make use of JavaScript and set the innerHTML of elements based on the user's input.

If you clarify a little more in the comments for this answer what exactly you're trying to achieve, I can give more specific help.

Comment: I updated the question, I hope this gives more information. Thank you!

Comment: Oh. Wait...are you running a web server with C?!?!

Comment: I guess so. I'm using an .html file to build my webpage with .c files to affect the .html file?